# How to programmatically scale up an ECS cluster with the AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am trying to scale up my ECS cluster programmatically with the `aws-sdk` package using node.js

I've read through the ECS portion of the API documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECS.html) a few times but cannot find an API method to update the configuration of an ECS cluster.

You can do this on the UI if you go into `ECS > clusters > your cluster > ECS Instances > Scale ECS Instances`:

[image: Scale ECS Instances]

Is there a way to do this programatically do this with the existing methods? Does there exist an `ECS.updateCluster` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, your cluster was created with the console first-run experience and that's why you were able to see Scale ECS Instances Option.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html

*If your cluster was created with the console first-run experience after November 24, 2015, then the Auto Scaling group associated with the AWS CloudFormation stack created for your cluster can be scaled up or down to add or remove container instances. You can perform this scaling operation from within the Amazon ECS console.*

*If your cluster was not created with the console first-run experience after November 24, 2015, then you cannot scale your cluster from the Amazon ECS console. However, you can still modify existing Auto Scaling groups associated with your cluster in the Auto Scaling console. If you do not have an Auto Scaling group associated with your cluster, you can create one from an existing container instance.*

I would not recommend using console for cluster creation in production environment. You should ideally use CF template to create cluster which can be placed AutoScaling Group.

You can modify AutoScaling Group desired count using following API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#setDesiredCapacity-property

```
var params = {
  AutoScalingGroupName: "my-auto-scaling-group", 
  DesiredCapacity: 2, 
  HonorCooldown: true
 };
 autoscaling.setDesiredCapacity(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I want. I'm trying to use the console to search for scaling groups but I don't think there's a product for that. Do you know how to find scaling groups associated with a cluster? Looks like I may have to create one but would like to know how to check if it exists before I do that.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized it tells you when you click the `Scale ECS Instances` button

Comment: yep. From UI, you can do it but I would not recommend that. Always, follow best practice and creating CF template and ASG groups makes your life a lot easy. If you are ok, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I mean I just get the scaling group name from the UI, I'm handling all the updates through code.

Comment: For anyone coming later, instead of using the `setDesiredCapacity()`, I instead used the `updateAutoScalingGroup` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#updateAutoScalingGroup-property). The reason being you can make one call and set desired capacity and max size in one request. If you try to `setDesiredCapacity`, it will fail if you try to set it higher than your max size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it via SDK directly. You have to use underlying ASG to set the desired count. As in the backend, ECS Cluster setup is done by the cloudformation template which creates an Auto-Scaling group for that EC2 pool.

You will be able to find the associated autoscaling group with the cluster in the ASG section of EC2. You can use SDK to update the desired count of that auto-scaling group, That will affect this desired count in ECS.

If you want to use autoscaling feature then you may use cloudwatch alarms to scale up and scale down instances based on different metrics say CPU Reservation/Utilization or MEMORY Reservation/Utilization.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html